# How to override ip admin login template?

Tags: php, impresspages

How to override ip admin login layout?

I created the file `'Theme/Air/override/Ip/Internal/Admin/view/loginLayout.php`

but this solution doesn't work.

Comment: Please see the fix bellow.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix https://github.com/impresspages/ImpressPages/commit/f047d7a6a414168acef3b2d1a6f7a4b460ef5aab

will be added to the next release.